# (1226, "User '*****' has exceeded the ' max_queries_per_hour' resource (current value: 1000)")

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

My project requires a lot of queries in selecting and updating... for long time.
I'm getting this error:

> MySQLdb._excpetions.OperatioanlError: (1226, "User '*****' has exceeded the 'max_queries_per_hour' resource (current value: 1000)")

Is there any solution to increase the number of maximum queries ?

Comment: "excpetions" -- really? Including the typo? Please quote your error messages verbatim (read [ask])! Also, take the time to throw the error message at a websearch engine. As a new user, please also take the [tour].

Comment: I think I didn't get the point across: If you retype error messages or code, information is lost and you should avoid that! Just use copy'n'paste instead. The simple reason is that this makes any analysis of your issue more guessing and less reliable. The given links give a bit of info how to avoid these pitfalls and ask good questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from [MySql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-resources.html) run the query

```
ALTER USER 'username'@'localhost' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 100000;
```

But I have to ask, why are you running so many queries?

Comment: Okay thank you. My project consists of monitoring the real traffic light by computing the numbers of cars in a permanent way using raspberry. Those parameters or changes  should be saved in database so that the computer does its own process to resend the action again to the raspberry through database.